# How to store JSON content in python project?

Tags: python, json

I have python project with JSON in it. And I have a lot of functions that called this JSON.

Now I call every time JSON (json.load) and use it's content.

Is it possible to open JSON once, store it's content and doesn't call it again? My JSON is static, means that I don't save data in it.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use json.dump() to store json content to file like this

```
import json

r = r.json()
with open(FILE, 'w') as f:
   json.dump(r,f)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a python file called "constants.py".

You can read constants in this file.

```
import json

with open("filepath/file.json", "r") as f:
    json_constants = json.load(f)
```

Then you just import this constant in other file.

```
from constants import json_constants

other scripts
```